# Percent chance to do something

Tags: c++

I have a 2D grid system for a game and I'm populating it with trees. I want a 25% chance to place a tree on a tile. However, I've done the below code and the trees are lined up perfect 1 in 4. I wouldn't think a 25% chance would ALWAYS result in such a uniform way to make perfect rows and cols of trees. They aren't staggered at all. This could just be me not understanding this but I would expect more variable tree placement if I want a 25% chance to place a tree. What am I missing here?

```
srand(time(NULL));

for (row = 0; row < 800; row++)
    {
        for (col = 0; col < 800; col++)
        {
            // 1 - 100
            int num = rand() % 100 + 1;

            // 25% chance to have a tree
            if (num <= 25)
            {
                // cal center tile position
                Vec3 pos;
                pos.x = ((col * .32) - (256 / 2)) + (.32 / 2);
                pos.y = 0;
                pos.z = (256 / 2) - (row * .32) - (.32 / 2);

                // create the tree object just to fill in it's data
                Item tree;
                tree.item_id = itemsList[(rand() % 2)];
                tree.owner_id = 0;
                tree.y_rotation = (rand() % 360);
                tree.x = pos.x;
                tree.z = pos.z;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where are you adding the tree to your game world? I suspect the problem is there and not `rand()`. [Here's a live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7b756d2c5953eb6d).

Comment: Please reduce your code to an example that shows that the random numbers are regularly distributed (which they shouldn't be). If you can't, then the code for placement is probably wrong.

Comment: You are right. I add these to a sql lite db and I was using sqlite3_bind_INT() and I should be using double. Thanks for the spark to find the problem.